# PHP script runs on local wamp, but errors on lamp set up on EC2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, wamp, lamp

I have a php class which tries to set a private static variable. It works on my local wamp, but when I upload it to an EC2 instance it will work once, then fatal error with access to undeclared static property. The class is an Amazon SimpleDb helper, I got it from http://webmasterinresidence.ca/simpledb/displayincludes.php . At first it was saying call to undefined function at line 100, so I changed it to set self::$__accessKey in the constructor, which is now the line the error occurs on. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Can you give us the error message, the whole error message as printed by your EC2 account.

Comment: Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: SimpleDB::$__accessKey in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/html/classes/sdb.php on line 114, the line number will be off I tried to change the class to see it I could fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Because it works the first time, then fails on subsequent attempts, do you have APC on the EC2 server and not your WAMP server? There is/was [a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59564) that causes static variables to not be recognized on subsequent attempts.

*(I would have asked more questions before proposing this answer but I can't comment yet!)*

Comment: Its not on my WAMP. I used this AMI [link](https://aws.amazon.com/amis/bitnami-lampstack-5-3-12-0-ubuntu-12-04). I didn't think it had APC on it.

Comment: It looks like it is included in that stack but it is unclear whether it is activated by default. You will be able to tell if it is active by looking in your [php.ini, or by creating a php_info.php](http://wiki.bitnami.org/Components/PHP#How_to_check_the_PHP_modules_installed.3f) file. While you are looking, it would be useful to compare the php version of your working server and the new one - or any differences in php.ini, if APC is not your problem.

Comment: It is a newer version of php, and APC is on. Besides that the only difference is debugging turned off. Is there any harm in deactivating APC?

Comment: It is worth disabling it to see if that fixes your issue. Make sure you restart Apache after you change php.ini to see the effects. [APC is a caching module](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/website-troubleshooting/introduction-apc-alternative-php-cache) that allows PHP to execute faster under certain circumstances. Disabling it should not break anything.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Accept answer?